# Why is LateX Suite (Vim) so inconsistent

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I am trying to transition to Latex Suite for Vim, but it seems to have several problems, observe:
[image: Latex Suite Screenshot]

The first `\subsection` command (90) is shown but the second one (124) is not. Again the third one is (132), but the fourth one isn't (154). A similar problem exists for the figure (163). There is other strange behaviour too, sometimes the `\begin{itemize}` doesn't fold at all, other times, only its individual items fold.

There seems to be no method to this madness, if I issue any of the commands

- `za`
- `zM`
- `zR`

nothing really changes. <del>If I have word wrap set, folding and unfolding might result in the entire line disappearing (until I scroll down)</del>.

Is this problem specific to me (ie. am I using it incorrectly, installed it incorrectly...) or is Latex-suite unreliable?

Comment: zE deletes all folds

Comment: @cmhughes these 'folds', they exist in memory right? As in if I reopen the file (or press F6... which doesn't work for me btw) then I get them back right?

Comment: @cmhughes WOW doing `zE` then reloading the file works! Is there any way to do it without reloading the file?

Comment: In a comment to my answer you stated that you have problems with your VIM configuration. Are you sure that what you percieve isn't effectively a problem with your local setup?

Comment: @DevSolar No the configuration issue was with remapping `;` and `:`. That might be why `F6` and `\rf` don't work, but I don't think it has anything to do with folding. In any case, I removed the option as you suggested as it is distracting.

Answer (score 6):

Not a "solution" to your problem, but I found the folding feature to be mostly in the way.

The line

```
let g:Tex_AutoFolding = 0
```

in my ~/.vimrc "solved" that problem for me. ;-)

Comment: you mean you manually reset the fold? via `\rf` I suppose? I am running into problems with my .vimrc file. A lot of commands like `\rf` or `F6` are not working for me so I can't test that out

Comment: @puk: No, I don't use folding at all. I use the above `.vimrc` line to keep LaTeX Suite from folding files on opening them. (I feel that folding stuff away from view is more a hindrance than a help, both with LaTeX and programming source.)

Comment: @puk: As for `.vimrc` troubles, since I am constantly moving between machines, I have stored my `.vimrc` configuration [online](http://dev.rootdirectory.de/wiki/.vimrc). Perhaps this "known good" (and commented) configuration might help you.

Comment: Impressive. Most Impressive.

Comment: To "celebrate" a recent upvote, that .vimrc of mine is now located [here](https://rootdirectory.de/doku.php?id=software:vimrc).